# How to use Transaction type Snapshot in PostgreSQL using java

Tags: java, postgresql, transaction-isolation

I have a requirement to execute DML commands in a microservice on the same database (Postgres) and commit in two phases.

I found transaction isolation snapshot as one of the solutions. I found in the documentation to create snapshot id first and use the same id in other transactions and finally commit transaction with this id.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
SELECT pg_export_snapshot();
 pg_export_snapshot
--------------------
 000003A1-1
(1 row)

BEGIN TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
SET TRANSACTION SNAPSHOT '000003A1-1';
```

Can some help me how to implement in java and if any documentation will help me?

Appreciate if any other solution for this scenario.

Comment: Are those separate servers that need to be changes in sync (in that case you might need 2 PC), or just replication would suffice?
Normally you need a transaction manage service which would use DB servers as resources. See also https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare-transaction.html

Comment: Can you please re-format this post to use Markdown formatting, in a code block?

Comment: Exporting snapshots is something you need if several sessions have to see the same state of the database, like in parallel operations. I don't see what you are driving at. Can you describe your requirements in more detail? Why the same snapshot?